# how to change color keeping gradients/opacity

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a problem

Lets say i have selected an area with is predominately one color lets say blue.
But this blue is not 100% blue in all places. Some pixels have some gradient to them etc.

How can i select this blue color and change it to say orange all so while keeping the gradients in the image i want to change? So if there are some 50% blue pixels and some 30% blue pixels in the selection how do i change the color so that these 50/30% blue will become 30/50% orange?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I answered a similar question earlier, that may help:
http://goo.gl/dV0HVI

Comment: You say predominately blue. Are there any other colors present that you need to avoid? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

With the limited amount of information that you have provided, I have what should be a simple solution.

Create a new layer above your existing gradient with whatever new color you want, and **set the blending mode to color** (it's in the layers panel at the top left). Then your gradient magically recolors itself!

[image]

Comment: wow thx! I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an image like this:
[image: initial]

Use the Magic Wand tool, select a pixel of the most typical color, adjust the Magic Wand tolerance to select the area you need to recolorize:
[image: selection]

Now you have multiple options:

- Use the Hue/Saturation dialog to change the hue to orange:

[image: Hue]

- Use the Levels or Curves dialog to increase red and decrease blue:

[image: Levels]

- Add a new layer, fill the selected area with orange and select an appropriate opacity and/or mixing mode:

[image: Glow mixing mode]